# js set default return value

Tags: javascript, chaining

TLDR; I like chaining methods but I have to add a `return this;` statement after each chainable method.

Is there a way to tell JS that for every method, if I don't return any value, then return `this`?

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. You have to be explicit.

Javascript functions always return `undefined` if no explicit return value is provided.

Comment: I've heard of a thing called TypeScript. It reads a .ts file and parses it into JS. Is there perhaps some interpreter (?) of that type that would automatically make all methods chainable when possible?

Answer (score 0):

At the end of function add

```
 if ([true statement]){

return [Object full];
}else{
 return;
}
```

then you had a return "default" if not

Comment: "but I have to add a `return this;` statement after each chainable method". That is the very thing I don't want to have to do.

Comment: Are you using any promissing method? can you explain a little more?

Comment: All I want is not to have to write anything and have the default return be `this`. Anything goes. If there isn't a way to do it in plain JS, I'll accept a parser that changes empty returns to `return this` and methods without return to have `return this` at the end. I just don't want to have to write it.